# How can I backup my data from a partition so that i can restore to windows later?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, backup

To start off I do not know much about Ubuntu in general so be gentle.

I tried to do a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu, which failed and I can no longer boot to windows because of a disk error. Ubuntu runs fine.

I never made a back up of my data before attempting the dual boot so I have all my data on a partition of my hard drive.

My question: How can I back up my data from a partition, using Ubuntu, so that I can do a clean reinstall of windows and restore my data from that partition so that it works with the windows file system?

Comment: Using Ubuntu, can you see your files from the Windows partition?

Comment: What disk error exactly are you faced with? What is the exact error message?